# 6502 XASM defini data

Tags: assembly, nasm, 6502

I  trying to understand DTA(define data) thing. Unfortunately i encounted problems such this one:

```
DTA b(0)
```

I can't really find what does it mean and do. Also examples on the site above  are unclear for me. Is there any better place to find out more about XASM and dta?
 I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Do you realize that you just give us a `file:///` URL to a resource local to your machine? Um, that's not going to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DTA b(0)` reserves one byte of *data* in your program, and initializes it to zero.

From the [MAD-ASSEMBLER documentation](http://mads.atari8.info/mads_eng.html#_dta):

```
DTA

The pseudo-command DTA defines typed data. If the type is not specified, byte data is assumed (b).
   b   byte data (8-bit)
   a   word data (16-bit)
   v   relocatable WORD data (16-bit)
   l   byte data (8-bit)
   h   byte data (8-bit)
   t   long data (24-bit)
   e   long data (24-bit)
   f   doubleword data (32-bit)
   g   doubleword data (32-bit) in reversed byte order (big-endian)
   c   ATASCII string, delimited by '' or ""; * at the end encodes inverse
       video, e.g. dta c'abecadlo'*
   d   INTERNAL string, delimited by '' or ""; * at the end encodes inverse
       video, e.g. dta d'abecadlo'*

Example:

  dta 1 , 2, 4
  dta a ($2320 ,$4444)
  dta d'sasasa', 4,a ( 200 ), h($4000)
  dta  c  'file' , $9b
  dta c'invers'*
```

It appears that this is implemented in XASM as well. See [xasm.d:2384](https://github.com/pfusik/xasm/blob/master/xasm.d#L2384).

Comment: what does it mean that it is initialied to zero?

Comment: i mean we make byte to represent 0 number. But how to get to it? We use dta and how to use it later on?